# Увеличить <div> при hover, но содержание чтобы осталось прежних размеров

Tags: html, css3

Не могу увеличить блок div  при hover і не увеличивать его содержание.
Нужен вот такой ефект
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;  
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: all .4s;
  
}
.card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.card:hover::before {
  content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -5%;
width: 110%;
top: -5%;
height: 110%;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
z-index: 3;
transition: all .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  lorem12 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Увеличение основного блока идёт на 25% (`scale(1.25)`), при этом дочерний блок-обёртка должен принимать -25% (`scale(0.75)`), тогда будет создаваться эффект увеличения блока - без увеличения содержимого.

Так же, чтобы крайние элементы не "увеличивались" за свои приделы - добавить `transform-origin` относительно "местонахождения блока".

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;  
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.section .item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vw;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.section .item > .wrap {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.section .item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.section .item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.section .item:hover > .wrap {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.section .item:first-child {
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.section .item:last-child {
  transform-origin: right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrap">
      <b>item 1</b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrap">
      <b>item 2</b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrap">
      <b>item 3</b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrap">
      <b>item 4</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать [трансформации](https://html5book.ru/css3-transform/). В данном случае `scale()`.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

div:hover .wrapper {
  transform: scale(0.9);
```

```html
<div><div class="wrapper">блок</div></div>
```

Comment: Ето да. Но при увиличении контент 'блок' тоже увеличивается. Надо без увеличения контента.

Comment: @OleksandrKhymych, исправил ответ

Comment: @Voprositel scale тут не надо делать для контента вообще типа

Comment: @МихаилКамахин почему бы и нет? Легче, чем писать скрипт.

Comment: @Voprositel без скрипта, просто надо css манипулировать

Comment: @МихаилКамахин а потом дело дойдет до адаптивности и всплывут проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Можем сделать с помощью относительного позиционирования. Отодвигаем блок на нужное кол-во пикселей влево и вверх и растягиваем.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #262626;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.card:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  padding: 60px;
  margin-right: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - вынести слой фона карточки из потока и его уже аниммировать

Пример

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  max-width: 33.3333%;
  width: 33.3333%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.card:hover:before {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.card__inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      <h2 class="card__title">Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam pariatur nulla culpa voluptatibus, velit facere dolores hic quis autem libero rem magnam suscipit assumenda non ad nemo neque unde sapiente.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      <h2 class="card__title">Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam pariatur nulla culpa voluptatibus, velit facere dolores hic quis autem libero rem magnam suscipit assumenda non ad nemo neque unde sapiente.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      <h2 class="card__title">Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam pariatur nulla culpa voluptatibus, velit facere dolores hic quis autem libero rem magnam suscipit assumenda non ad nemo neque unde sapiente.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне Ваш ответ понравился больше других ответов